# Create SQLite3 tables with C, but got an empty database file

Tags: c, database, linux, sqlite

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

#define DBFILE "./userinfo.db" //It's empty file

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int retval;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    sqlite3 *handle;

    retval = sqlite3_open(DBFILE, &handle);
    if(retval)
    {
        perror("sqlite3_open");
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("Connection successful...\n");
    char create_table[] = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"
    "users(uname TEXT PRIMARY KEY, pass TEXT NOT NULL)";

    retval = sqlite3_exec(handle, create_table, 0, 0, 0);
    if (retval)
    {
        perror("sqlite3_exec");
        exit(-1);
    }
    sqlite3_close(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it and run it without any errors.

Before I run it, the database file `userinfo.db` is an empty file

after I run it, I got a `empty database file` again.

Why? table didn't be saved?

Comment: `char create_table[] = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"
    "users(uname TEXT PRIMARY KEY, pass TEXT NOT NULL)";` shouldn't this be just one string?

Comment: You need a space between EXISTS and users, but no clue why there's no error.

Comment: @IonutHulub Two string literals with only whitespace between them gets automatically concatenated as a single string literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get:

```
$ testprogram
Connection successful...
sqlite3_exec: No such file or directory
```

or, when the file already exists:

```
$ testprogram
Connection successful...
sqlite3_exec: Success
```

The reason is that the `sqlite3_*` functions do not set `errno`, which is the error code output by `perror`.

To output SQLite error messages, use `sqlite3_errmsg`:

```c
fprintf(stderr, "sqlite3_exec: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(handle));
```

With that, I get:

```
$ testprogram
Connection successful...
sqlite3_exec: near "EXISTSusers": syntax error
```